# How can we code to arbitrarily control the size of TCP packets sent out in Linux?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, packet

We are doing a senior design project where our code needs to send data to another computer with the ability to define each TCP packet size to be a random value between 100 to the MTU boundary.

We cannot change Linux's MTU value since it will affect the entire OS and other running processes. We think one way is to modify Linux kernel code modules, another way is kernel hooking. Could anyone tell us where we can start? Will both approaches work?  Thanks!

Comment: Can’t you just disable Nagle/use TCP_NODELAY of a socket in your test program ?

Comment: if you're looking for a way to hook/replace some function in kernel/kernel_module, take a look at LSMs (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.16/admin-guide/LSM/index.html) (how they work), ftrace (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt)  and kprobes (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt). Recently was introduced another way - fprobes (https://docs.kernel.org/trace/fprobe.html) - hooks based on kprobes

Comment: Simply using TCP_NODELAY as HS2 suggests above and sending one packet at a time of the wanted size should be enough for what you describe. Have you tried this?

Comment: TCP is a byte stream protocol, so disabling the Nagle algorithm using TCP_NODELAY will make TCP send data immediately without waiting for more data from the application. For example, if it receives 10 bytes, it will send it right away. But how could we define the packet size in this case? For example, what if I want to collect 50 bytes to perform a send operation?